# Запрос SQLite по поиску номера в базе данных контактов

Tags: android, sqlite, запрос

Всем привет. Есть такая проблема: пишу прогу для android - список контактов и хочу, чтоб когда пользователь вводит номер телефона, сделать запрос по поиску номера в базе данных и вывести результат имение контакта в textview, заранее спасибо.

Comment: И в чём проблема? Запрос не знаешь как написать?

Comment: да android я немного знаю а вот с sqlite еще не работал

Answer (score 1):

Если в `contactNumber` хранится телефонный номер искомого контакта, то имя контакта `contactName` можно найти c помощью [android.provider.ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) так:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(contactNumber));
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

String contactName;

try {
    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToNext();
        contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
} finally {
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: но это как я понимаю надо запрос для контактов из самого телефона или из моей программы?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Cursor DB_GET_NAME(int nomer) //узнаём имя  
 {       
   return DataBase.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM TableName WHERE tel = nomer, null);
 }
```

- name - название столбика где хранятся имена.
- TableName - название таблицы.
- tel - название столбика где хранятся телефонные номера.
- nomer - тот номер, по которому тебе надо найти.

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: Мой пример это если ты хочешь вытянуть имя, из собственной базы, а если хочешь вытянуть имя, из базы телефона, то тебе нужен код из второго ответа.

Comment: а return  DataBase - это имя моей базы данных?

Comment: DataBase - это название ОБЪЕКТА SQLiteDatabase, при создании которого указывается ИМЯ базы данных. Почитай пару примеров про работу с базами на андроиде и поймёшь многое! http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite.php
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/simplydatabase.php

Comment: Пример, вообще не о том. В Android номера телефонов недоступны в виде прямого SQLite запроса. Надо смотреть в сторону `ContactContract`

Comment: "Barmaley" Ну так я в комментарии к ответу чётко написал, что этот ответ предназначен для собственной базы программы, а ответ пользователя "sddfg" предназначен для вытягивания данных из базы телефона.